# How to view the capacity metric from Storm's UI, over a custom time interval?

Tags: apache-storm

The Storm UI provides a (seemingly) very useful capacity metric. But it only displays it for the past 10 mins. Is there a way to view this for a custom time interval? Possibly through the UI or via the command line?

Edit: A similar question. The visualization tool in the Storm UI shows some percentages, but I can't find any documentation on what these percentages indicate. Do they indicate how full a Bolt's input queue is? Or what percentage of time is spent in a certain Bolt? Or something like this?

Comment: Did you find out what the percentages are? I'm also looking for this info.